Oracle EBS Application user keep on receiving email notification that is already closed
A particular end-user of Oracle EBS R12.2 application, keeps on receiving closed workflow email notification.
The email notification status is "CLOSED" and the mail status is "SENT".
The end-user is receiving the  mail for closed old notification.
The WF_NOTIFICATION_OUT table does not have any  corresponding record.
The body of the notification mail shows below given message:
You earlier received the notification shown below.  That notification is now closed, and no longer
requires your response. You may simply delete it along with this message.
I have bounced the Workflow  components including the notification mailer.
Verified the user's mail preference and ensured it as MAILHTML.
